# Does there exist an efficient way of doing a wavefront iterator? (Not physics related.)

Tags: algorithm, f#, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

```
// https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/optimizing-recurrent-neural-networks-cudnn-5/
// The last optimization from the above post. This is a sorting based implementation.
// I can't think of anything more elegant that a state machine at the moment

let wavefront_order =
    [|
    for x=0 to 49 do
        for y=0 to 9 do
            for z=0 to 9 do
                yield (x,y,z)
    |]
    |> Array.sortBy (fun (x,y,z) -> x+y+z)
```

As a matter of fact, running a recurrent NN without sorting it by distance from the origin would work, but would be nowhere near as efficient. Using multiple streams, the Cuda scheduler would get clogged up if I do not launch the kernels in the wavefront order.

That I need the above for NNs, or the example being in F# is purely for context.

I know how to do it for two dimensions, but for 3D and more, all I have in mind is a bit hacky. I was wondering if there was some elegant way of doing the wavefront iteration similar to the sorting based approach above for arbitrary dimension lengths and number of dimensions?

Comment: Well one obvious approach would be effectively to pre-sort which would just require one more over-arching loop.

Comment: I do not understand. What is a pre-sort?

Comment: something like `for sum=0 to (49+9+9) do , for x=0 to min(sum,49), for y=0 to min(sum-x,9), for z=0 to min(sum-y-x,9)`

Answer (score 2):

```
let x_len = 49
let y_len = 9
let z_len = 9

let presort =
    [|
    for sum=0 to x_len+y_len+z_len do
        for x=0 to min sum x_len do
            for y=0 to min (sum-x) y_len do
                let z = sum-x-y
                if z <= z_len then yield (x,y,z)
                |]
```

This works beautifully, it is exactly what I wanted. Thank you, John Palmer.